# Conversion Constructor in C++

Tags: c++

Program below is giving error 'invalid use of incomplete type class Rectangle' and 'forward declaration of class Rectangle'. How to fix this without editing any header file? Isn't there any possible way to do the conversion using constructor only?

```
include<iostream>
include<math.h>

using namespace std;

class Rectangle;
class Polar
{
    int radius, angle;

public:
    Polar()
    {
        radius = 0;
        angle = 0;
    }

    Polar(Rectangle r)
    {
        radius = sqrt((r.x*r.x) + (r.y*r.y));
        angle = atan(r.y/r.x);
    }

    void getData()
    {
        cout<<"ENTER RADIUS: ";
        cin>>radius;
        cout<<"ENTER ANGLE (in Radians): ";
        cin>>angle;
        angle = angle * (180/3.1415926);
    }

    void showData()
    {
        cout<<"CONVERTED DATA:"<<endl;
        cout<<"\tRADIUS: "<<radius<<"\n\tANGLE: "<<angle;

    }

    friend Rectangle :: Rectangle(Polar P);
};

class Rectangle
{
    int x, y;
public:
    Rectangle()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    Rectangle(Polar p)
    {
        x = (p.radius) * cos(p.angle);
        y = (p.radius) * sin(p.angle);
    }

    void getData()
    {
        cout<<"ENTER X: ";
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"ENTER Y: ";
        cin>>y;
    }

    void showData()
    {
        cout<<"CONVERTED DATA:"<<endl;
        cout<<"\tX: "<<x<<"\n\tY: "<<y;
    }

    friend Polar(Rectangle r);


};
```

Comment: you can't fix this without using a header file, 2 actually... or at least separating the definition from the declaration at a minimum

Comment: What is the real goal behind "without editing any header file"? It seems like an arbitrary restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix this without editing any header file.

You can't. The definition of `Polar(Rectangle)` will have to come after the definition of `Rectangle`, so that `Rectangle` is complete where the constructor needs to use it.

Just declare the constructor in the class definition:

```
Polar(Rectangle r);
```

and define it elsewhere; either in a source file, or in a header after defining `Rectangle` (in which case you'll need to mark it `inline`).

Personally, I'd tidy this up by splitting it into two headers, one per class, and defining all the members in source files (unless I've proved that they need to be inline for performance reasons). Then the headers will each only need to declare the other class, and only need to be included from the source files that implement or use the classes.

Comment: How to do this using 'inline'. Plz share it ! & why we need to mark the function inline.

Comment: @m0rpheus: `inline Polar::Polar(Rectangle r) {/*function body*/}`, exactly as your introductory book described.

Comment: can't we do this without using inline. i mean just defining the constructor outside of class, as you said!

Comment: @m0rpheus: If you define it outside the class, in the header, it needs to be inline (as I showed you in the comment above). If you define it in a source file, it mustn't be inline (it would look the same, but without the `inline` keyword). You have to do one of those two things, since the third option (defining it in the class) is impossible due to the dependency on `Rectangle`.

Comment: i've define it outside the class using scope resolution operator. But it's giving the same error.

Comment: @m0rpheus: I guess you put the definition before that of `Rectangle`. It has to come after it. The circular `friend` declarations are problematic too. It might be easier to just declare the class a friend (`friend class Rectangle;`) or make the necessary data available through the public interface.

Comment: I've defined it after class Polar & Rectangle. someone told me that this approach is not possible and we have to create header file. Plz look at @zenith 's comment. So,  i wanna know if that is possible or not !

Comment: @m0rpheus: It's possible, as I've described; I've no idea why you still get an error. It's not advisable, as I've described; but you should be able to bodge it all into one header if that's really what you want. Here's a working example (I just added a `main` function to the end so it could compile as a program): http://ideone.com/oZZmMc. But you really should break it down into nicely structured headers and source files.

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to access the incomplete type `Rectangle` in your `Polar(Rectangle)` constructor.

Since the definition of the `Rectangle` constructor also needs the complete definition of `Polar`, you'll need to separate the class definition from the constructor definition.

Solution: Put the definitions of your member functions in a .cpp file, as you should be doing, like this:

**polar.h:**

```
class Rectangle; // forward declaration to be able to reference Rectangle

class Polar
{
    int radius, angle;
public:
    Polar() : radius(0), angle(0) {} // initializes both members to 0
    Polar(Rectangle r); // don't define this here
    ...
};
```

**polar.cpp:**

```
#include "polar.h"
#include "rectangle.h" // to be able to use Rectangle r

Polar::Polar(Rectangle r) // define Polar(Rectangle)
:   radius(sqrt((r.x*r.x) + (r.y*r.y))),
    angle(atan(r.y/r.x))
{
}
```

The above initializes `radius` and `angle` to what's inside the brackets.

**rectangle.h:**

```
class Polar; // forward declaration to be able to reference Polar

class Rectangle
{
    int x, y;
public:
    Rectangle() : x(0), y(0) {} // initializes both x and y to 0
    Rectangle(Polar p); // don't define this here
    ...
};
```

**rectangle.cpp:**

```
#include "rectangle.h"
#include "polar.h" // to be able to use Polar p

Rectangle::Rectangle(Polar p) // define Rectangle(Polar)
:   x((p.radius) * cos(p.angle)),
    y((p.radius) * sin(p.angle))
{
}
```

I also showed you how to use *constructor initialization lists* which you should be using in C++ to initialize member variables.

Comment: @zenith : but i mentioned above, i don't wanna create any header file. can you plz share the code of  defining the constructor outside. i've done it. but it's giving the same error !

Comment: @m0rpheus It's not possible without a header. And all the code is in my answer already? The constructors are defined outside the class definition, in cpp files.